# How to change an xml file from another page in html

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am making a javascript library(hopefully I can complete it), and so I want to know the name of the sites that are using the script. I made an XML file `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <logs> <sites></sites> </logs>`, with this code. I have the following code in the javascript library:

```
waste.runner = function(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "logs.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();

    function myFunction(xml) {
        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var x;    
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("logs")[0].getElementsByClassName('sites');
        x.nodeValue += "site:"+window.location.href+";";
    }
}
```

I looked through countless sites but none of them solve the problem, and I have reached this code. Is there any way I can change the data of an XML file using HTML and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Js can't do that.
The change happens within the browser, and it remains there.
You should make a request to the server and send the name of the website, and the server should save the input in some file or db.
I advice you to use the fetch API instead of XHR.
Your js will be:
fetch('example.php?website='+window.location.href)
inside fetch you will put the name of a file on your server.

Comment: Can you explain more? I am not familiar with PHP or SQL or MongoDb or Fetch Api